# sqlserver Stop executing on any error

Tags: sql-server-2008, error-handling

I want to stop executing on any error occured with out using "try catch",why some errors stop executing while others dont do Examples

**Example 1:**

```
select 5;
exec( 'select * from tttt') ; -- tttt is not table
select 6
```

I can sett in result

```
5 and 6 and Error Msg Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Invalid object name 'tttt'
```

in this case I want to skip out

**Example 2:**

```
select 5;
update t1 set ID=1   ;--ID is Primary Key
select 6
```

the result is only Error Msg

```
Msg 8102, Level 16, State 1, Line 3,Cannot update identity column 'ID'.
```

I know Example2 Error is on compilation time and Example1 Error is on executing time, But this is just example what I want.
for Example 1 I want the result to be 5 ,  Error Msg Msg 208 without continuing exeuting to return 6, All that without using try catch or raiseerror or comapring @@ERROR=0